# How to add more spaces between two rows of images in Quarto for PDF output?

Tags: r, pdf, quarto

I have three images aligned in three rows.

In the same block layout, I have to use

```
:::{layout="[[1], [-1], [1], [-1], [1]]"}
![](iamge1)
![](image2)
![](image3)
:::
```

to increase the space between them. But the space is still small.

If I put them into separate blocks, it looks like the same as above.

How can I add more spaces between two rows of images in an PDF output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your output format is pdf, you can use *latex* command `\vspace` to increase the vertical space between the figures.

```
---
title: "Spaces"
format: pdf
---

## Quarto


![](placeholder.png){width=20%}

\vspace{2em}

![](placeholder.png){width=20%}

\vspace{2em}

![](placeholder.png){width=20%}
```

[image: vertically spaced figures]

---

If you need more space increase the value of `\vspace{}` from *2em* to *3em* or *4em* etc.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I didn't realise that I could mix with layout block with LaTeX. I am just in the process to covert whole block to LaTeX syntax right now.